# Why does MSVC 12.0 ignore private constructors if the copy assignment operator is deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
private:
    Test() = default;
};

Test t;

int main() { }
```

Both MSVC 12 and 14 (Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, respectively) refuse to compile this, as expected - the constructor is private and so we cannot create objects of that type outside of the class itself.

However, let's now make one small change:

```
class Test
{
private:
    Test() = default;
    Test operator=(const Test& rhs) = delete;
};

Test t;

int main() { }
```

To my surprise, it will compile fine in MSVC 12 (14 still gives the same error). Why is it so? My first thought was that maybe this was standard behavior in an older version of C++, but then I realized that the very concept of deleting constructors was only introduced in C++11.

Is this a bug?

Comment: VS2012 was too early to hope for complete C++11 compliance.  It took them a while, they had to completely rewrite their front-end to get there.  Technical debt from a code base that was written to target a machine with 256 KB of memory.  That work was completed for VS2015.

Comment: Touches on the question of whether `Test` is an aggregate. Thorny issue.

Comment: @HansPassant: re "That work was completed for VS2015", I think I recently read a blog posting from the dev team that they're still at it, and doing great stuff. Do you have any more information about the "completed"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, MSVC 12 does have partial c++ 11 support, but I do believe that compiling is a bug. I encountered something similar using MSVC 12 where I could access private fields from non-static template functions, when I clearly shouldn't have. It was a coding oversight that strangely compiled. I thought it was weird so I compiled it with GCC and sure enough GCC said "No Good!". I think it was fixed in the November CTP though, since I can't seem replicate it.